# What's the rule about UnsafePoint and Swift Object? Here are some code

Tags: swift, pointers

I try to learn a framework about **JSON**. Framework name is ***HandyJSON***.And I have some problems about Pointer.

I only know the class property can show in the struct, is right?

**What's the mean of "func class_rw_t()"?**

*Why "databits_t & fast_data_mask" can point to the "_class_rw_t"? And Why "fast_data_mask" is "0x00007ffffffffff8"?*

**Code:**

```
struct _class {
var kind: Int
var superclass: Any.Type?
var reserveword1: Int
var reserveword2: Int
var databits: UInt
// other fields we don't care

func class_rw_t() -> UnsafePointer<_class_rw_t>? {
    if MemoryLayout<Int>.size == MemoryLayout<Int64>.size {
        let fast_data_mask: UInt64 = 0x00007ffffffffff8
        let databits_t: UInt64 = UInt64(self.databits)
        return UnsafePointer<_class_rw_t>(bitPattern: UInt(databits_t & fast_data_mask))
    } else {
        return UnsafePointer<_class_rw_t>(bitPattern: self.databits & 0xfffffffc)
    }
}}

struct _class_rw_t {
var flags: Int32
var version: Int32
var ro: UInt

func class_ro_t() -> UnsafePointer<_class_ro_t>? {
    return UnsafePointer<_class_ro_t>(bitPattern: self.ro)
}}

struct _class_ro_t {
var flags: Int32
var instanceStart: Int32
var instanceSize: Int32}


class TestModel {}

let c = TestModel()
let pointer = unsafeBitCast(TestModel.self, to: UnsafePointer<_class>.self)
let instanceStart = pointer.pointee.class_rw_t()?.pointee.class_ro_t()?.pointee.instanceStart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you pasted accesses internal details of the Objective-C runtime. It's very advanced and very fragile. If I were you, I would stay far away from this library.

The `_class_rw_t` type is for accessing the `class_rw_t` struct defined in [`objc-runtime-new.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-723/runtime/objc-runtime-new.h.auto.html). You can also see the definition and use of `FAST_DATA_MASK` in that file. You will need to know C++ to understand the Objective-C runtime source code.

Comment: Thank you, objc-runtime-new.h is what i need.